# How to Find Command Line before Boot-Up

Tags: boot, command-line, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

Ubuntu 14.04 was working fine for a few weeks after installation, detecting USB wireless Microsoft all-in-one keyboard/touchpad. Then it stopped, at least after boot-up.
Keys work before boot-up to input passwords, touchpad moves mouse pointer after boot-up, but clicking is impossible, and no typed keystrokes are registered, so I cannot open a Terminal window.

If I unplug and replug the mouse, it stops working altogether. I've tried other non-wireless mice and Logitech keyboards, but they don't work either.
Starting from Recovery is the same thing. The keyboard works fine before boot-up, so I am trying to get to a Command line from Recovery. Dropping to root shell prompt leaves me with read-only files, and I can't operate commands.
Going to `repair broken packages (dpkg)`, I thought should take me to a Command line, but it always runs through to 98%, then freezes for hours until I have to force restart (holding the power button down, which I know is a bad thing).

What other ways are there to get to a Command line?

Comment: Did you try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or F2,F3..,F6) after booting normally?

Answer (score 0):

sorry i confused your question, usually i press ctrl+alt+F1 for login to cli mode, but when your keyboard isn't working how to going there. Hmm, maybe you want to change your first boot to command line mode you can get it [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/) but thats work after boot option menu entered [i mean grub menu].

Comment: When I press ctrl+alt+F1 as it prompts me to enter passphrase, it sends me to a purple background with a cursor, where i can type commands, but they have no effect. The instructions in the link you gave would work if I could get the computer to detect my ctrl+alt+T command after boot-up, but I cannot. Is there another way?

Comment: okkay, you can try to boot via usb and try without installations next go to your real ubuntu file system, not file system on your usb boot and then follow that link instructions to change first boot.

Comment: Was just starting along the same path. Quick question: How do I get to my real Ubuntu file system from the trial version of USB drive Ubuntu?

Comment: simple, on file manager have available about some path like computer,devices, and network. You can see your real ubuntu on path devices and your trial ubuntu on path computer.

Comment: OK, I did that, and it prompted me to enter my passphrase cause my system is encrypted. However, a window popped up saying "Unable to access "128 GB EnCrypted" -- The unlocked device does not have a recognizable file system on it

Comment: Is it possible to open a Terminal window that goes to me real file system via a USB?

Comment: don't use default file manager but nautilus, you can use it by type sudo su on your terminal and type nautilus, wait a moment... next nautilus file manager will appears.

Comment: Me again. I get an error message... "Oops! Something went wrong. Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created: /root/.config/nautilus

Comment: ok, what do you do before that?

Comment: I followed your instructions. After opening Ubuntu trial version from USB, I opened Terminal, then typed command "sudo su" followed by "Nautilus". Then that error message pops up. In the Terminal it says Error no such file or directory, followed by "Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing." The Nautilus window looks very limited, just has Home, Desktop, Trash, Computer, Browse Network and Connect to Server.

Comment: i mean login your terminal trial ubuntu version as root, then type nautilus and you can see on left panel, entered your real ubuntu version file system, and next follow that link for change your first boot mode.

Comment: after i type sudo su, it changes my login to root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#... is that what you mean by logging into my terminal trial version as root?

Comment: yes, follow next instructions...

Comment: I did, it leads me in circles... i type in Nautilus, it gives me the above error message i told you about, then opens a limited version of nautilus in which i cannot see my other computs. I can see more in the default file manager.

Comment: Ok try again, and when you still cannot see your other computs, press F9 to see your other partitions

Comment: Absolutely no effect. I admit, I have already given up and tried to reinstall, but it has failed from two different USB disk installation drives... it keeps freezing in installation. Could it be a hardware issue? It was all working fine, I changed nothing except adding updates and then blammo... stopped working.

Comment: After re-install, I went to recovery mode, and Dropped to Root Shell Prompt, which sent me to a command line, no problem.

Comment: Okkay, I am also pleased your problem is solved :)